# Script tag in astro component doesn't work when included in content collection

Tags: html, typescript, astrojs

So I want to make something with script tag, but the script tag doesn't work

Here is my content collection

```
---
title: Essay Similarity
stakeholder: THESIS
articleDate: 05 Feb 2023
projectStart: 2022-08-01
projectFinish: 2022-12-01
tags: 
- php
description: A plugin that hopefully help teachers to auto grade student answer by comparing the similarity of student’s answer and teacher’s answer key with machine learning
sourceCode: https://github.com/thoriqadillah/essaysimilarity
next: 'Wangsit'
---

import Cossim from "@components/Cossim.astro";

...some texts

<Cossim/>
```

And here is my Cossim.astro component

```html
---
import Button from "./Button.astro";
---

<div class="mb-2">
  <label for="lang" class="text-bright font-bold mr-3">Language</label>
  <select name="lang" id="lang" class="prose dark:prose-invert bg-dark p-2 rounded-md">
    <option selected value="none">None</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="id">Indonesia</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row">
  <textarea class="prose dark:prose-invert docs bg-dark rounded-md w-full p-3 mb-2 md:mr-2 h-36" placeholder="Write something"/>
  <textarea class="prose dark:prose-invert docs bg-dark rounded-md w-full p-3 mb-1 h-36" placeholder="Write something else"/>
</div>

<Button color="second" roundtype="md" classname="calculate mt-1">Calculate</Button>
<p id="result" class="text-second inline p-2 font-bold ml-auto"></p>

<script>
  alert('aaa')
</script>
```

Indeed, the component will be displayed on the page, but the script does not work
When the page is loaded, there is no alert whatsoever. When I tried to ad `is:inline` it works, but the problem is, I want to import some typescript into the tag to do some logic, and when the `is:inline` is present, it throws some error. This also happen when I tried to add `type="module"` on the tag. How to solve this? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue in early releases of Astro v2 but should be fixed as of Astro 2.0.4. Relevant issue on GitHub is here: https://github.com/withastro/astro/issues/5991

Could you try updating to `astro@latest` to see if this is still an issue?